# How to use (link) debug version of libc++ in macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm, libc++

I want to enable debug version of `libc++` in macOS, so I define `_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1` in `cxx_build_flags` [[Debug Version of libC++]](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html#using-debug-mode),
but unable to link debug function of `libc++`. I guess there is only release version of `libc++` in my system, so how can I get the debug version of `libc++` in macOS

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::__1::__libcpp_db::__decrementable(void const*) const", referenced from:
  void std::__1::__nth_element<std::__1::__debug_less<std::__1::__less<float, float> >&, std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*> >(std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*>, std::__1::__debug_less<std::__1::__less<float, float> >&)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a debug-build of the standard library? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: I just want to enable assert function(such as index check in vector) to detect incorrect usage of the standard library

Comment: How do you compile your project? Have you add `-D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1` to `CFLAG`?

Comment: yes, I add -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1 to cxxflags ,then debug functions in std headers are enabled, but no implementation in released version of std lib.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got this to work!

So the steps I took,

1. Check your toolchains `__config` file for `_LIBCPP_VERSION`'s value.
2. Browse the source repo for the commit where that version was set
3. From that commit, find the `debug.cpp` file
4. Include/compile/link the `debug.cpp` with your project (and remember to set `_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1`).

For me the intermediate results for the steps were (with Catalina, XCode Version 11.3.1)

- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__config` was at version `8000`
- Looking at the history at [https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commits/main?&path[]=libcxx&path[]=include&path[]=__config](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commits/main?&path%5B%5D=libcxx&path%5B%5D=include&path%5B%5D=__config) I found commit https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/25977548aa5ad7cfe45a17e4ba136abfa4613b96#diff-0a85f740cd20254bc3bb03975c89d93a
- The `debug.cpp` for that commit is at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/25977548aa5ad7cfe45a17e4ba136abfa4613b96/libcxx/src/debug.cpp

Comment: Nice, worked fine! Here's a tip, just use the blame view of the __config file https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blame/main/libcxx/include/__config and click on the button to go back to the previous commit for that line, that'll allow you to quickly jump to the commit that changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I try to reactivate this thread without an answer with more details.

I have the same issue. This is very easy to reproduce:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  return 0;
}
```

and then compile with:

```
clang++ -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG=1 main.cpp
```

We obtain:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__libcpp_db::__insert_c(void*)", referenced from:
      void std::__1::__libcpp_db::__insert_c<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in main-7ff3c5.o
  "std::__1::__libcpp_db::__erase_c(void*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() in main-7ff3c5.o
  "std::__1::__c_node::~__c_node()", referenced from:
      std::__1::_C_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~_C_node() in main-7ff3c5.o
  "std::__1::__get_db()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string() in main-7ff3c5.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() in main-7ff3c5.o
  "typeinfo for std::__1::__c_node", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::__1::_C_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > in main-7ff3c5.o
  "vtable for std::__1::__c_node", referenced from:
      std::__1::__c_node::__c_node(void*, std::__1::__c_node*) in main-7ff3c5.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And if I use `g++-9` providen by brew (a real g++ not a disguised Apple Clang compiler), it compiles and runs perfectly.

Forgetting to use debug mode of libc++, is it the only solution?

NB: I saw the same question in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99194
and still no answer.